# link to currently logged in user's profile in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am trying to link to a devise users profile

```ruby
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  #get '/users/:id', :to => 'users#show', :as => :user
  resources :users

  root to: "welcome#index"
```

My User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/avatar/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

My Link

```
<li><%= link_to (image_tag current_user.avatar.url(:thumb)), user_path(current_user.id), class: "navbar-link" %></li>
```

I have the same setup as

[User profile pages with devise - Routing to show action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449573/user-profile-pages-with-devise-routing-to-show-action)

I am getting this error

uninitialized constant UsersController

thanks

Comment: Do you have a `users_controller.rb` file under the `app/controllers/` directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `devise_for` in your routes file automatically creates the routes required for devise to work. The controllers for devise are packaged inside the gem and not visible to you.

Calling `resources :users` afterwards means rails will look for a controller called UsersController which is not a controller used by devise anyways. You do not have a UsersController in your app/controllers directory and that is the reason why you are getting said error.

Devise is a solution that works out of the box and to customise the controllers or views, you need to copy the appropriate files to your application. There is commands that will easily allow you do that. All of this information (and more) can be found [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started). Of particular interest is the section "Configuring controllers".

It is always good practise to read a gem's basic documentation before getting started.

**EDIT:** It appears that devise does not automatically create a show action for a user, hence why a separate controller is necessary. Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086583/creating-a-users-show-page-using-devise) for a related question on how to set up a view action for a user.

Comment: I missed that part about the gem. I have removed my resources :users and destoryed my controller and views. I then ran rails generate devise:controllers users. I still do not see how to go to the current_user profile (show) page. There doesn't seem to be a any extra code need as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449573/user-profile-pages-with-devise-routing-to-show-action).

Comment: Ha! I see what's going on. Devise does not actually automatically create a show action for a user profile and that's what your linked SO question alluded to. My mistake. Take a peek [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086583/creating-a-users-show-page-using-devise), that should explain what you need to do. Apologies for the earlier confusion.

Comment: Thank you sir! I am sorry I didn't find that question earlier.